# How do I console log my new state using firebase snapShot.val()?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, webpack, firebase-realtime-database

I'll try and keep it simple and concise.

I have started a simple page with React Webpack and Firebase included.

1. I set the initial state for **DVDLibrary** as null.
2. Inside the **componentDidMount** function I set the state as a firebase snapShot.val().
3. When I console.log the DVDLibrary state, it logs null.

```js
import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import firebase from 'firebase';

    export default class Front extends React.Component {
    
      constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
          DVDLibrary : null
        };        
      };
    
      componentDidMount(){
        firebase.database().ref().on('value',snapShot => {
            this.setState({
              DVDLibrary: snapShot.val()
            });
        });
        console.log(this.state.DVDLibrary);
      };
      
      render()....
      
    }
```

If I include the contents of the **componentDidMount** function inside the **constructor** function, the console logs as expected but the new state doesn't seem to leave the scope of the constructer.

I tried to include a console.log in a **componentDidUpdate** function but it didn't log anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks All.
Moe

Comment: Move `console.log(this.state.DVDLibrary);` into the `on` callback - immediately after the `this.setState` call. The `on` is asynchronous.

Comment: @cartant That's fine, the issue is that the new state isn't in the scope of the website. So although including the console log after setState works, I still can't render the data(state) on the page. It also means I cannot map the data to components either.

Comment: Calling `setState()` should force a rerender. If that doesn't happen or if something goes wrong during the render, please include the code that is failing. It might be easiest if you post a reproduction of the problem on jsbin.

Comment: Thanks for the input @FrankvanPuffelen. A setState on componentDidMount doesn't seem to work. The way trick I used was to change  DVDLibrary : null to DVDLibrary : []. That works. Is this good practice in general with React.

Comment: The `setState` call does not happen when `componentDidMount` runs, but when the `on('value'` callback returns (which is likely much later). At that point calling `setState` should trigger a re-render with the updated state.